# unbounded metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be an unbounded metric space. Is it right to say:
There are a $c\in X$ and $\{x_n\}_{n \in {N}}\subset X$ such that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}d(x_n,c)=+\infty$?

Comment: Take $c\neq x_1$ to be any two points of the space. If all other points were inside the ball of radius $r_n=\max(n, d(c,x_n)+1)$. Then the distance between any of them would be not larger than $2r$, by triangle inequality. Therefore there is some point $x_{n+1}$ outside that ball.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).